# How can I fix the cannot convert type error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a details page about a movie, but I´m getting this error and I´m kinda stuck. I'm getting a cant convert type error. I do understand the error, but I dont have any idea of how to fix it.

This is the Index the PAP Entities is the Database instance:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{

    PAPEntities db = new PAPEntities();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        }).ToArray();

        return View(movies);

    }
```

And this is my details class for now:

```
public ActionResult Details(int Id = 1)
    {
        MovieViewModel MovieVM = db.MoviesData.Find(Id);
        return View(MovieVM);
    }
```

I keep getting the error on the "db.MoviesData.Find(Id);"

This is the MovieViewModel code:

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
    public string MovieCategory { get; set; }
    public string MovieYear { get; set; }
}
```

This is the razor page:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel[]


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Movie Name </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Category </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Year </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Description </b></th>
        <th></th>


    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.MovieID</td>
        <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
        <td>@item.MovieYear</td>
        <td>@item.MovieDescription</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieID })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebApplication3.Models.MoviesData' to
>   'WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel'

The MoviesData is the database's table

Comment: Show us the razor page please.

Comment: In `Index()` you do `new MovieViewModel { ... }`. You also need to do that in `Details()`.

Comment: @CodeNotFound i answered myself with the razor page

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira you should delete. I added the razor wiew to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ActionResult Details` method `db.MoviesData.Find(Id)` returns object which type is `WebApplication3.Models.MoviesData` but your variable type is `MovieViewModel`. That's why you are getting exception.

You need to cast manually. So, You can code like this,

```cs
public ActionResult Details(int Id = 1)
{
    MoviesData movie = db.MoviesData.Find(Id);
    MovieViewModel MovieVM = new MovieViewModel{
        MovieID = movie.MovieID,
        MovieName = movie.MovieName,
        MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
        MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
        MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
    };

    return View(MovieVM);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should map your DB (`MoviesData`) model To Bussiness model (`MovieViewModel`)

```
   public ActionResult Details(int Id = 1)
    {
        MoviesData movie = db.MoviesData.Find(Id);
        MovieViewModel MovieVM = new MovieViewModel();
        MovieVM.MovieID = movie.MovieID;
        MovieVM.MovieName = movie.MovieName;
        MovieVM.MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription;
        MovieVM.MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory;
        MovieVM.MovieYear = movie.MovieYear;

        return View(MovieVM);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried it and it appears the error: " The name "movie" does not appear in the current context". Do I need to change something?