# Im getting a wrong type in Edit Controller, what should i do?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently doing a Edit class in the main controller. It seems to be everything fine, but there's an error when I build the program

This is the class Edit in the MoviesController:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                MoviesData moviesData = db.MoviesData.Find(Id);
        if (moviesData == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(moviesData);
    }
```

(MoviesData is the database's table instance)

This is the View model:

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
    public string MovieCategory { get; set; }
    public string MovieYear { get; set; }
}
```

Everytime I try to build the program this error appears:

'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MoviesData_4D99853B016ED5E65AF8566A78AEB274D91AD066D99E2B2FA50D6EA0156AAA21', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel'

I understand what the error means, but I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: You're not returning a `MovieViewModel` to the view.  You're returning `MoviesData`.  Convert `moviesData` to a view model

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, `db.MoviesData.Find(Id);` is returning you **Model**, but `return View(moviesData);` this needs viewModel, kindly convert your model into viewModel

Comment: @haldo How can I convert the moviesData?

Comment: Hi. This is your seventh basic C#/MVC question within a week, which is solvable by researching the error and putting some effort in trying to understand the issue. This is the same issue as in [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322230/how-can-i-fix-the-cannot-convert-type-error). I'd suggest you follow a decent tutorial or book on ASP.NET MVC and C#, and not ask a new question for every problem you encounter, or you risk a question ban very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the DTO to your viewmodel:

```
MovieViewModel viewModel = new MovieViewModel()
{
   MovieID = moviesData.MovieID (or maybe only .ID?),
   MovieName = moviesData.MovieName

   etc....

}

return View(viewModel );
```